# What does `idem` mean in the VIM docs?

Tags: vimscript, help-system

One example would be in the List docs:

```
:unlet list[3] "idem
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's [a latin term meaning "the same"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idem). In the quoted context, it just means the listed command does the same thing as the previously listed command, i.e. `remove item 3`:

```
:let i = remove(list, 3)    " remove item 3  
:unlet list[3]              " idem
```

Comment: Fun fact: in Italy the term "idem" is often used when, for example, giving orders at the restaurant when people take the same dish. A: "Prendo la fiorentina con l'insalata" B: "idem con patate" (A: "I'd take the Fiorentina steak with salad", B:"The same, but with potatoes instead"). In particular "idem con patate" is often used to state, in a generic comparison between two things, that they are not exactly the same, but in practice they should be considered the same.

Comment: In Germany, people might say "dito" for same situation that @GiacomoAlzetta described.

Comment: @Rolf "Ditto" is common in English, too. I've never heard "Ditto with potatoes," though.

Comment: @Rich Yes, in Germany would also only say "dito" without anything else afterwards.

Answer (score 6):

`:help list`

```
...
:let i = remove(list, 3)            " remove item 3
:unlet list[3]                      " idem
:let l = remove(list, 3, -1)        " remove items 3 to last item
:unlet list[3 : ]                   " idem
...
```

`idem` is to say that that line of code does the same as the line above.

This could be useful: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/idem